# How can I toggle active, calculator buttons with keyboard evenlisteners?

Tags: event-listener

window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {

```
e.preventDefault();

let userInput = e.key;

let button = document.querySelectorAll('button');

switch (userInput) {
    

default:
            userInput = e.key;
            break;
        case 'Escape':
            calculator.clear();
            calculator.updateDisplay();

            button[0].style.background = 'black';
            break;
        case 'Backspace':
            calculator.delete();
            node.updateDisplay();

            button[1].style.background = 'black';
            break;
        case '/':
            calculator.chooseOperation('÷');
            calculator.updateDisplay();
            button[2].style.background = 'black';
            break;
        case '1':
            calculator.appendNumber(userInput);
            calculator.updateDisplay();
            button[3].style.background = 'black';
            break;
        case '2':
            calculator.appendNumber(userInput);
            calculator.updateDisplay();
            button[4].style.background = 'black';
            break;
        case '3':
            calculator.appendNumber(userInput);
            calculator.updateDisplay();
            button[5].style.background = 'black';
            break;
        case '*':
            calculator.appendNumber(userInput);
            calculator.updateDisplay();
            button[6].style.background = 'black';
            break;
        case '4':
            calculator.chooseOperation(userInput);
            calculator.updateDisplay();
            button[7].style.background = 'black';
            break;
        case '5':
            calculator.appendNumber(userInput);
            calculator.updateDisplay();
            button[8].style.background = 'black';
            break;
        case '6':
            calculator.appendNumber(userInput);
            calculator.updateDisplay();
            button[9].style.background = 'black';
            break;
        case '+':
            calculator.appendNumber(userInput);
            calculator.updateDisplay();
            button[10].style.background = 'black';
            break;
        case '7':
            calculator.chooseOperation(userInput);
            calculator.updateDisplay();
            button[11].style.background = 'black';
            break;
        case '8':
            calculator.appendNumber(userInput);
            calculator.updateDisplay();
            button[12].style.background = 'black';
            break;
        case '9':
            calculator.appendNumber(userInput);
            calculator.updateDisplay();
            button[13].style.background = 'black';
            break;
        case '-':
            calculator.appendNumber(userInput);
            calculator.updateDisplay();
            button[14].style.background = 'black';
            break;
        case '.':
            calculator.chooseOperation(userInput);
            calculator.updateDisplay();
            button[15].style.background = 'black';
            break;
        case '0':
            calculator.appendNumber(userInput);
            calculator.updateDisplay();
            button[16].style.background = 'black';
            break;
        case 'Enter':
            calculator.appendNumber(userInput);
            calculator.updateDisplay();
            button[17].style.background = 'black';
            break;
        case 'Enter':
            calculator.compute();
            calculator.updateDisplay();
            button[18].style.background = 'black';
            break;
}
```

});

```
window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
let userInput = e.key;
let button = document.querySelectorAll('button');
```

switch (userInput) {
default:
userInput = e.key;
break;
case 'Escape':
button[0].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)';
break;
case 'Backspace':
button[1].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)';
break;
case '/':
button[2].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)';
break;
case '1':
button[3].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)';
break;
case '2':
button[4].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)';
break;
case '3':
button[5].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)';
break;
case '*':
button[6].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)';
break;
case '4':
button[7].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)';
break;
case '5':
button[8].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)';
break;
case '6':
button[9].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)';
break;
case '+':
button[10].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)';
break;
case '7':
button[11].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)';
break;
case '8':
button[12].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)';
break;
case '9':
button[13].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)';
break;
case '-':
button[14].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)';
break;
case '.':
button[15].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)';
break;
case '0':
button[16].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)';
break;
case 'Enter':
button[17].style.background = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)';
break;
}
});